¿Por qué la anotación @ModelAttribute no obtiene el objeto del modelo despues de que se envía el formulario?
Según la documentación oficial la anotación @ModelAttribute cuando se aplica a un parámetro de método, obtiene el objeto del modelo (cuyo nombre se especifica en el argumento de la anotación) y lo asigna al parámetro del método, pero esto no sucede en el ejemplo que muestro a continuación:
@Controller

public class Controlador {
    
    @RequestMapping
    public String mostrarPaginaInicial() {
        return "paginaDeBienvenida";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mostrarFormularioDeVehiculo")
    public String muestraFormulario(Model modelo) {
        Car carro = new Car();
        carro.setManufacturer("nuevo valor");
        modelo.addAttribute("carro", carro);
        return "formularioVehiculo";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/procesarFormularioVehiculo")
    public String procesarFormularioVehiculo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("carro") Car carro, BindingResult resultadoValidación) {

        if (resultadoValidación.hasErrors()) {
            return "formularioVehiculo";
        } else {
            return "inspeccionTecnicaDeVehiculo";
        }
    }
}


public class Car {

    @NotBlank 
    private String manufacturer ="valor por defecto";

    @NotBlank 
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
    private String licensePlate;

    @Min(2)
    private int seatCount;

    // setters y getters
}

formularioVehiculo

    <body>
    <h2>Registro del vehículo</h2>
    
    valor del atributo manufacturer: ${carro.manufacturer}
    <br><br>
    <form:form action="procesarFormularioVehiculo" modelAttribute="carro">

        Matrícula: <form:input path="licensePlate" />
        <form:errors path="licensePlate" style="color:red" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Nº de asientos: <form:input path="seatCount" />
        <form:errors path="seatCount" style="color:red" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Siguiente">
    </form:form>
</body>

En este ejemplo, en el formulario "formularioVehiculo", el campo correspondiente al atributo manufacturer del objeto de modelo "carro" no está presente. Cuando se muestra este formulario, la expresión ${carro.manufacturer} muestra el valor "nuevo valor". Luego, al enviar el formulario con algún campo inválido la validación falla y en consecuencia el formulario se vuelve a mostrar. En este caso, la expresión ${carro.manufacturer} ya no muestra el valor "nuevo valor", sino el valor "valor por defecto". Esto indica que la anotación @ModelAttribute no está recuperando el objeto del modelo a cuyo atributo "manufacturer" se le asignó el valor "nuevo valor" en el método muestraFormulario antes de añadirlo al modelo. En lugar de eso, la anotación está creando una nueva instancia de ese objeto, lo que explica por qué el valor de su atributo manufacturer es el predeterminado, es decir, "valor por defecto".
Sin embargo, al anotar la clase Controlador con @SessionAttributes("carro"), que indica que el objeto carro se almacena en la sesión, el comportamiento es el esperado y se muestra el valor "nuevo valor". Esto plantea la pregunta: ¿Por qué la anotación @ModelAttribute no obtiene el objeto del modelo como se afirma en la documentación oficial? ¿Es necesario siempre usarla junto con @SessionAttributes para obtener el objeto del modelo? De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.
